# break while loop whthin with a if condition

Tags: python, boto

I'm working on a project to automate AMI creation. 
Requirement: 1. create an AMI
             2. wait until the AMI created
             3. break the loop if the AMI creation failed or success
             4. repeat the procedure for all instances

we don't want to reboot the instance when we create the AMI.

Problem: script is not terminating inner while loop when i add the break statement to a if condition. can someone please help me to fix the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import boto
import boto.ec2
import datetime
import time

list_1 = ['instance1','instance2']
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-1',aws_access_key_id = '<access_key>',aws_secret_access_key = '<secret_key>')

def create_img(a, b):
    try:
        print "Starting AMI creation for : %s" % inst.tags['Name']
        img_id = conn.create_image(a, b, description='backup', no_reboot=True, dry_run=False)
    except boto.exception.BotoServerError, e:
        print e.error_message
    return(img_id)


reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
for res in reservations:
    for inst in res.instances:
        if 'Name' in inst.tags and inst.tags['Name'] in list_1:
            print "%s (%s) [%s]" % (inst.tags['Name'], inst.id, inst.state)

            name = inst.tags['Name'] + '-' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
            ami_id = create_img(inst.id, name)
            img = conn.get_all_images(filters={'image_id' : ami_id})[0]

            if img.state == 'failed':
                print "AMI creation failed for instance: %s" % inst.tags['Name']
            elif img.state == 'pending':
                while True:
                    if img.state == 'failed':
                        print "AMI creation failed for instance: %s" % inst.tags['Name']
                        break
                    elif img.state == 'available':
                        print "AMI creation completed for instance: %s" % inst.tags['Name']
                        break
                    else:
                        time.sleep(60)
            elif img.state == 'available':
                print "AMI creation completed for instance: %s" % inst.tags['Name']
            else:
                print "Couldn't find the AMI"
```

Comment: What is it printing?

Comment: I see the AMI created, But loop was not terminated and didn't go to the next instance.
output-->instance1 (i-xxxxx) [running]
Starting AMI creation for : instance1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the state by calling `img.update()`.  State information doesn't automatically update.  A call to AWS is only made in response to an boto API call.

```
        img = conn.get_all_images(filters={'image_id' : ami_id})[0]

        if img.state == 'failed':
            print "AMI creation failed for instance: %s" % inst.tags['Name']
        elif img.state == 'pending':
            while True:
                if img.state == 'failed':
                    print "AMI creation failed for instance: %s" % inst.tags['Name']
                    break
                elif img.state == 'available':
                    print "AMI creation completed for instance: %s" % inst.tags['Name']
                    break
                else:
                    time.sleep(60)
                    img.update()
```